# Angular4 upgrade animation not working

Tags: angular, animation

I have recently upgraded my angular app from angular2.4.0 to angular 4.0.0.
I have followed this [link](http://angularjs.blogspot.in/2017/03/angular-400-now-available.html)
It compile without any error, Only 3 warnings it gives.
here is attached screenshot of warning.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIpCf.png)
But the animation not working.
Please check what I am missing.
Thanks in advance.

**package.json**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "angular2-modal": "2.0.2",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "ng2-translate": "2.5.0",
    "rxjs": "5.2.0",
    "typescript": "^2.2.2",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.2.2",
    "zone.js": "0.7.4"
  },
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { BaseComponent } from '../base/base.component';
import { ViewContainerRef, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { trigger, transition, style, animate, state } from '@angular/animations';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';


@Component({
    selector: 'verification',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
    providers: [BaseComponent],
    animations: [
        trigger('trans', [
            // What happens when toggleState is true
            // state('true' , style({ opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(0)', offset: 0 })),
            state('true', style({ transform: 'translateY(0)' })),
            // What happens when toggleState is false
            // state('false', style({  opacity: 0, transform: 'translateX(100%)', offset: 0, position:'absolute', right:-9999 })),
            state('false', style({ transform: 'translateY(20%)' })),
            // transition
            transition('0 => 1', animate('0.2s 100ms ease-in')),
            transition('1 => 0', animate('0.3s 25ms ease-out'))
        ])
    ]
})
export class VerificationComponent {
    public verifySuccess:boolean;
    constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute, private base: BaseComponent) {
        this.verifySuccess = true;
    }

}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <div class="backstretch">
    </div>
    <div class="vefification">
        <div class="verification-content">
            <div class="verification-main p-20" [@trans]="verifySuccess">
                    <div *ngIf="verifySuccess">                                        
                        <h3>YOU'RE ALL SET</h3>                    
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button class="btn-resend-email" type="submit" (click)="verifySuccess=true">RESEND EMAIL</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>                   
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**app.modulte.ts**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule,
                  BrowserAnimationsModule,  
                  BootstrapModalModule,
                   ],
  declarations: [ //components
                  VerificationComponent,
                  ]    })

export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently ran in to a similar issue. And managed to solve it by changing my states - that trigger the animations - to strings.

I was using `0` and `1` as states to trigger the animation in 2.X. After upgrading to 4.X I didn't get errors, but it would not trigger animations properly. Switching to only strings made it work again. Since you seem to be using booleans I would try switching to strings and it might start working again for you.

So `this.veryfySuccess` could be `'no'/'yes'` instead of `true/false`. You would also need to update your `transition` in the animation from `0 => 1` to `no => yes` as well as your `state` declarations within the `trigger`.

Comment: thanks It worked for me too. I changed the states to string and assigned same value as states to them. then it worked.I think it should work with boolean values and states, I don't know why it does not work with boolean values.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. I agree that it should work with numbers/booleans. But I was just surprised that they didn't mention this in their upgrade notes.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to import again the `BrowserAnimationsModule` in your app.component.ts. You should declare it once in your `NgModule`.
You probably have some typo in your template because your upgrade seems okay.

Comment: yeah, but we have commented BrowserAnimationsModule from app.component.ts but still problem remain same

Comment: @PravinMishra Hmm, can you show your verification.compontent.html?

Comment: the verification.component.html is same as app.component.html while edit I forgot to change templateUrl